# Cannot open passkit file created in the server using dotnet-passbook v3.0.2

Tags: .net-core, passbook, wallet, passkit, apple-wallet

I have recently come across an issue that I cannot open my Pkpass which is created using dotnet-passbook version 3.2.0.

The Pkpass created locally can be opened fine and the issue is with the Pkpass created in the server.

I have even tried to upload the Pkpass from the server to the validator but the [validator](https://pkpassvalidator.azurewebsites.net/) just returns “Failed to process the Pkpass file.”

Below is my code snapshot for building the Pkpass:

```
    public static FileContentResult GetPass(Shopper account)
        {
            try {
                if (account == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                PassGenerator generator = new PassGenerator();
                PassGeneratorRequest request = new PassGeneratorRequest();

                // "webServiceURL" : "https://example.com/passes/",
                // "authenticationToken" : "vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc",

                // Product info
                request.PassTypeIdentifier = "PassTypeIdentifier";
                request.TeamIdentifier = "TeamIdentifier";
                request.SerialNumber = "SerialNumber";
                request.Description = "Description";
                request.OrganizationName = "OrganizationName";
                request.LogoText = "LogoText";

                // Add the installed certificate and it's thumbprint
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                try
                {
                    X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;
                    request.PassbookCertificate = new X509Certificate2(webClient.DownloadData(CertificatesBucket + "/Certificates.p12"), S3_AppleCertificatePassword, flags);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occurs when geting certificate: " + e.Message);
                }

                // Add Apple's WWDRCA certificates
                try
                {
                    request.AppleWWDRCACertificate = new X509Certificate2(webClient.DownloadData(CertificatesBucket + "/AppleWWDRCAG2.cer"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occurs when geting AppleWWDRCCA: " + e.Message);
                }
                // override icon and icon retina
                try
                {
                     request.Images.Add(PassbookImage.Logo, webClient.DownloadData(AppleImageBucket + "/logo.png"));
                     request.Images.Add(PassbookImage.Icon, webClient.DownloadData(AppleImageBucket + "/icon.png"));
                     request.Images.Add(PassbookImage.Icon2X, webClient.DownloadData(AppleImageBucket + "/icon%402x.png"));
                     request.Images.Add(PassbookImage.Strip, webClient.DownloadData(AppleImageBucket + "/strip.png"));
                     request.Images.Add(PassbookImage.Strip2X, webClient.DownloadData(AppleImageBucket + "/strip%402x.png"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occurs when geting images: " + e.Message);
                }
                // Add barcode
                request.AddBarcode(BarcodeType.PKBarcodeFormatCode128, account.Id, "ISO-8859-1");

                // Link the pass to an existing app using the app's Apple ID.
                request.AssociatedStoreIdentifiers.Add(121212);

                request.Style = PassStyle.StoreCard;

                // Add fields
                request.AddHeaderField(new StandardField("StandardField", "TEXT", account.Id));
                request.AddSecondaryField(new StandardField("StandardField", "TEXT", account.Name));
                request.AddSecondaryField(new StandardField("StandardField", "TEXT", "TEXT"));

                request.TransitType = TransitType.PKTransitTypeAir;

                byte[] generatedPass = generator.Generate(request);
                //throw new Exception("apple generatedPass: " + JsonTransHelper.SerializeObject(generatedPass));

                return new FileContentResult(generatedPass, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error occurs when creating apple pass: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by AWS API Gateway. If you running this on a Lambda function try to invoke it directly.

[Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64 .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555736/offset-to-central-directory-cannot-be-held-in-an-int64-net-core)